# Taking a screenshot of screen session over ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, irssi

I often log via ssh to servers just to execute `screen -r` and look at my irssi irc session. Then I do `Ctrl-AD` and `logout`.

Is there a nice solution to wrap this into a script, so that I get to see the snapshot of my screen session in any format (graphical, or text)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a "screenshot" of a screen session like this:

```
screen -p0 -X hardcopy hardcopy.txt
```

So this will take a hardcopy of whatever is in the first window (`-p0`) and put it in a file called `hardcopy.txt` (if you leave off the filename, it will use `hardcopy.n` where `n` starts at zero an increments each time.

The screenshot is on the remote machine, and I guess you want to view it.  Perhaps something like:

```
ssh user@remote 'screen -p0 -X hardcopy hardcopy.txt; cat hardcopy.txt'
```

You could also log your irssi session, so the following would work:

```
ssh user@remote 'tail -50 /path/to/irssi/log'
```

If you want a screenshot that maintains colors, then that would depend a bit on the OS and desktop environment you sshing from.